# use cases of geocoding maps

Tags: visualization, data-analysis, geospatial, tableau

Tableau has interactive maps that can be used for custom geocoding. I know companies often divide regions for sales and marketing purposes but could anyone think of any specific use cases or examples where custom geocoding could be used?

For example, we could further divide a city into different areas? But what else?

Comment: Locations of projects, of offices, data collection sites, employment data by firm, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a dashboard for an advertising campaign.  The zipcodes of where adds were sent, distance of zicodes from nearest brick-and-mortar.  You can radial select and see costs, profits, etc) and modify where you send your ads.